# Properties not yet proven for neural networks but proven for regression

Tags: regression, neural-networks, references

This question is a *bit vague*:  Are there any properties postulated for feed-forward neural networks which are not yet proven and have a known analogue in classical linear regression analysis?

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. In order to not make this an opinion based discussion: what kind of properties do you mean, and where should this postulation have happened? It might also be relevant what the motivation for the question is.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome.  I was wondering something along the lines of a Bayesian interpretation of (penalized) regression.  Something that has not been proven for ANNs because of their difficult structure.